# Maven dependency scrubber?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

The question is how to scrub a `pom.xml` and remove unnecessary dependencies by trial-and-error? I imagine this algorithm exists which works by removing each dependency and executing `mvn test`, then putting the dependency back if the test fails, or leaving it out permanently if the test succeeds. What is the command, plug-in, utility, or other thing I need in order to perform this simple task? Google search was fruitless.

Answer (score 0):

`mvn dependency:analyze` - this could show you the dependencies that you don't need. At least it'll shorten the list of dependencies you would need to check.

There are other analyzing goals that this plugin has, so take a closer look at the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/).